# Algorithm, finding "number not divided by square numbers" between given min and max value

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes

> ***Problem***
>
> There is a minimum value min and maximum value max, find all the
>   numbers which not divided by "square numbers" between min and max. (1<=min<=1trilion, max-min<=1,000,000)
>
> ***Example***
>
> min is 1, max is 10.
>
> The answer is 7 from 1,2,3,5,6,7,10 because 4,8 is divided by square number
>   2^2=4.

---

My approach.

1. All numbers divided by square number are also divided by square prime number.
2. Using seive of eratosthenes, computed all the square prime numbers smaller than sqrt(max)
3. Finding all numbers divided by above suqare prime numbers.

But I got "time limit" or "Wrong" from that site. How can I prove? Below is code.

```
void Eratos()
{
    for (ll i = 2; i <= primeMax; i++) num[i] = i;

    for (ll i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
        for (ll j = 2; j <= primeMax; j++) {
            if (num[j] == -1) continue;
            else if (num[j] > i && num[j] % i == 0) num[j] = -1;
        }
    }

    for (ll i = 2, j = 0; i <= primeMax; i++) if (num[i] != -1) {
        prime[j] = num[i]*num[i];
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Naive, doubly-nested loop "solutions" to these online judge sites almost always results in time-out errors.  Also, I don't recommend these sites -- they do not teach you how to properly write programs.

Comment: Try another approach: generate numbers which is divisible by square numbers, than just put them in set, after this you can check if number is divisible by square in `O(log n)` or `O(1)` if u'll use `unordered_set`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I agree with you that online judges don't teaches good style coding, or solving architecture problems. But judges direction is improving your algorithm skills. So if u want to learn algorithms - they are good for this

Comment: @oybek you mean the STL "set" of C++?

Comment: @haram yep, but I think `unordered_set` is better here

Comment: By the way, I like to refer to people that use things like `printf` and `scanf` in C++, as `C+` developers, a strange breed that never *quite* made the transition fully. Paraphrasing Yoda: C++ or C++ not, there is no try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are checking check all numbers in range (nr=max-min) against all primes (np), so complexity is `O(nr*np)`.

But instead you can make list of prime squares and use Eratosthenes sieve approach again over min..max range, marking squareful numbers. So code will make about

```
Sum (nr / (sq[0]) + nr / (sq[1]) +...nr / (sq[np-1])
```

steps with complexity (perhaps) about `O(np + nr)`

For example, range is 50...80. Prime square list is 4,9,25,49. Make boolean or bit array with 31 entries. First run marks entries 52,56,60..80. Second run: 54, 63, 72; third run marks 50,75, and fourth marks nothing. Now unmarked entries 51,53,55..79 is what you need.

The first entry in range, divisible by some square psq is

```
((min + psq - 1) div psq) * psq
```

Delphi code gives result 607923 in 0.1 second

```
function CountSquareless(AMin, AMax: Int64): Integer;

var
  PrSqList: TList<Int64>;

procedure MakePrimeList; //Eratosphenes sieve
var
  num: array of Byte;
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(num, 1000001);
  PrSqList := TList<Int64>.Create;
  for i := 2 to 1000000 div 2 do
    for j := 2 to (1000000 div i) do
       num[i * j] := 1;
  for i := 2 to 1000000 do
    if num[i] = 0 then
       PrSqList.Add(Int64(i) * i);
end;

var
  num: array of Byte;
  i, nr: Integer;
  psq, first: Int64;
begin
  nr := AMax - AMin;
  SetLength(num, nr + 1);
  MakePrimeList;

  for psq in PrSqList do begin
    first := ((AMin + psq - 1) div psq) * psq;
    while first < AMax do begin //Eratosphenes-like sieve uses prime squares
      num[first - AMin] := 1;
      first := first + psq;
    end;
  end;

  Result := 0;
  for i := 0 to nr - 1 do
    if num[i] = 0 then
      Result := Result + 1;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(CountSquareless(1000000000000 - 1000000, 1000000000000)));
```

c++ code for sieve

```
using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;
const int primeMax = 1000000;
int num[primeMax + 1];
ll prime[100000];
int primecnt = 0;

void Eratos()
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= primeMax; i++) num[i] = i;

    for (int i = 2; i <= primeMax; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= primeMax / i ; j++) {
             num[i * j] = -1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= primeMax; i++)
        if (num[i] != -1) {
          prime[primecnt++] = (ll)num[i] * num[i];
      }
    cout << "last prime squared " << prime[primecnt-1] << " number " << primecnt;
 }
```

Comment: I don't totally understand what "marking squareful numbers" mean. Can you explain more easily?

Comment: Mark numbers divisible by prime squares. I'll write short example soon.

Comment: I don't know Delphi and I don't understand your logic. But your answer is  
 great. Thanks

Comment: Emm.. Do you understand Eratosthene logic? It is the same approach on shifted (by AMin) range

Comment: I know the sieve of Eratosthenes and I used in my algorithm. Did you use this to 1 million number?

Comment: Yes, in MakePrimeList (analog of your Eratos) exactly million. In main function - depending on range size (in my example - million too)

Comment: I edited my sieve of Eratosthenes code. Can you check? I computed prime numbers to 1 million and check as "-1". Using "prime" array, I got square prime numbers.

Comment: Sory, but you didn't catch essence of sieve - it does not check every number wit all possible divisors, it just marks non-primes. Look at my c++ version in edit (perhaps weird, but works)

Comment: I totally understood the sieve algorithm. Thank you! I got "correct" by your algorithm. But I didn't understand `((min + psq - 1) div psq) * psq` how this works. sad..

Comment: Example: you need the first number after 10 divisible by 7. It definitely lies in range 10..10+7-1. Make **integer** division of the largest value in this range by 7: 16/7 = 2 and multiply by 7: 2*7=14 - it is needed value.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the problem statement asks you to "find *all* the numbers which not divided" (sic), the fact that you only have *one* `printf` and it's not inside a loop of some sort, seems to indicate your solution is more on the "wrong" side of the ledger rather than the "time limit" side.

I'd suggest fixing *that* before you worry about speeding it up. You can't get any *less* optimised than "wrong" :-)

---

The *first* thing you should have done is to see what output you got from the input given in the test case - you would have immediately seen that speed is not the issue here:

```
pax> echo 1 10 | ./testprog
7
```

Now my eyes might be getting a bit old nowadays but even *I* can see there's a difference between `7` and `1,2,3,5,6,7,10`.